# getting data from textboxes using a jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capture the values of pairs of textboxes on my page.

I am capturing them, but it's not exactly working the way I'd want it to as I am getting duplicate data.

Here's my HTML code:

```
    <div id="links">
        <div id="group1">
             <input type="text" name="linkTitle" value="Google">
             <input type="text" name="linkURL" value="www.google.com">
        </div>

        <div id="group2">
             <input type="text" name="linkTitle" value="Yahoo">
             <input type="text" name="linkURL" value="www.Yahoo.com">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="btnSaveLinks" type="button" value="Save">
    </div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
    $("#btnSaveLinks").on('click', function() {
       $('#links input[type=text]').each(function () {
          var title = $(this).attr("value");
          var url = $(this).attr("value");
          console.log('title: ' + title);
          console.log('url: ' + url);
       });
    });
```

title: Google

url: Google

title: www.google.com

url: www.google.com

title: Yahoo

url: Yahoo

title: www.yahoo.com

url: www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting duplicated data because you are iterating over every input and then storing the same value in the two variables:

```
var title = $(this).attr("value");
var url = $(this).attr("value"); // same thing
```

Your variables `title` and `url` contain the same thing.

You could iterate over your divs and then get the inputs inside them:

```
$('#links div').each(function() {
      var title = $(this).find('[name=linkTitle]').val();
      var url = $(this).find('[name=linkURL]').val();
      console.log('title: ' + title);
      console.log('url: ' + url);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zXTEC/

Answer (score 1):

It's duplicated because you're writing the value twice for each text box with this line `$(this).attr("value");` Look at your code again and you'll see that you use this same line for each box to get the value and assign it to two different variables...